# MongoDB query double nested array with matching sets

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Being not familiar with Mongo and still progressing I came accross a problem I can't think to fix (and I don't know if it's feasible)

I have an `Event` document whose structure looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": "6138451fb3a7d9564a0229fd"
    "title": "Event  1",
    "cohortsGroups": [
        [
          {
            "_id": "6124beef59d728c82088fd59",
            "name": "2022",
            "type": "promotion"
          }, 
          {
            "_id": "6124bf2159d728c82088fd60",
            "name": "Toronto",
            "type": "city"
          }
       ],
       [
         {
            "_id": "6124beef59d728c82088fd57",
            "name": "2024",
            "type": "promotion"
          },
          {
            "_id": "6124bf2159d728c82088fd68",
            "name": "Tokyo",
            "type": "city"
          }
        ],   
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "6138451fb3a7d9564a0229fe"
    "title": "Event 2",
    "cohortsGroups": [
        [
          {
            "_id": "6124beef59d728c82088fd59",
            "name": "2022",
            "type": "promotion"
          }
        ]
     ]
},
{
    "_id": "6138451fb3a7d9564a0229fh"
    "title": "Event 3",
    "cohortsGroups": [
        [
          {
            "_id": "6124beef59d728c82088fd21",
            "name": "2022",
            "type": "promotion"
          },
          {
            "_id": "6124beef59d728c82088fd43",
            "name": "Amsterdam",
            "type": "city"
          }
        ]
    ]
}
```

As you can see the field `cohortsGroups` is a double array of Objects. I would like to retrieve those events based on my user's object who possess also an array (simple) of `cohorts`

So for example let's say my user looks like this:

```
{
 "firstName": "John",
 "lastName": "Doe",
 "cohortsRef": [
   {
    "_id": "6124beef59d728c82088fd59",
    "name": "2022",
    "type": "promotion"
   },
   {
    "_id": "6124bf2159d728c82088fd60",
    "name": "Toronto",
    "type": "city"
   }
 ]
}
```

To make it simple I would like to retrieve an event only if one of the set of `cohorts` in in his `cohortsGroups` have his cohorts all presents in the user object.

Taking that in mind and the above example I would only be able to retrive `Event 1` and `Event 2`.
I can't retrieve `Event 3` because even tho I have the Cohort `2022` in my user, it's paired with the Cohort `Amsterdam` which is not present in my user's cohorts, (eq: none of the cohort subarrays sets have their values entirely present in my user's cohorts).

I really hope someone can give me a hand on that problem, so far I've tried to map all the user's cohorts ID in an array and query by `$elemMatch`

`Events.find({ cohortsGroups: { $elemMatch: { $elemMatch: { _id: { $in: [ '6124beef59d728c82088fd59', '6124bf2159d728c82088fd60' ] } } } } })`

But this solution just retrieves every event that have a subarray cohort matching, it doesn't take into account the `sets`, so in this case it would also retrieve `Event 3` - because `2022` is present - but it's paired with the cohort `Amsterdam` which is wrong.

Let me know if I wasn't clear enough, any help would be appreciated. At least to know if it's something doable as a mongo query.

Thanks a lot for reading !

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
db.events.find({ cohortsGroups: { $elemMatch: { $not: {$elemMatch: { _id: { $nin: [ '6124beef59d728c82088fd59', '6124bf2159d728c82088fd60' ] } } } } } })
```

The outer `$elemMatch`, matches any document where any array in cohortsGroups matches the inner condition.

The inner condition

```
{ $not: {$elemMatch: { _id: { $nin: [ '6124beef59d728c82088fd59', '6124bf2159d728c82088fd60' ] } } } } }
```

is using a double negative with `$not` and `$nin` to find subarrays that have no element with an `_id` except those that you are searching for.